# Facebook Feed Error

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am getting ad feed error,An error occurred. Please try again later. for the below code .

```
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=107100136150735&link=http://www.facethered.com&picture=&name=Experience the terror of The Red in Tampa.&caption=http://www.facethered.com&description=See the trailer and get free tickets to an exclusive premiere near you.&redirect_uri=http://www.facethered.com"><img src="images/new_send.png"></a>
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your link is wrong. Are you trying to go to somewhere specific?
Tell us more.

Is this what you want?

```
   <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

Are you trying to link from your website to your facebook page?

Comment: here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/yusQV/. I need to send a message.http://jsfiddle.net/yusQV/ its full code. need functionality like http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 1):

Your link doesn't seem to go anywhere. You might want to double check that the link is correct.

Where do you want this link to go?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yusQV/ its full code. need functionality like http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/